# Applying different styles to the same elements in CSS

Tags: css, xml

Suppose I have the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="email.css"?>
<!DOCTYPE emaillist [
<!ELEMENT emaillist (email)>
<!ELEMENT email (to,from,sub)>
<!ELEMENT to (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT from (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sub (#PCDATA)>
]>

<emaillist>
    <email>
        <to>john@gmail.com</to>
        <from>smith@gmail.com</to>
        <sub>Application leave</sub>
    </email>
    <email>
        <to>alex@gmail.com</to>
        <from>rutherford@gmail.com</to>
        <sub>Resignation</sub>
    </email>
    <email>
        <to>michael@gmail.com</to>
        <from>jackson@gmail.com</to>
        <sub>Enrollment</sub>
    </email>
</emaillist>
```

And here is the email.css file:

```
emaillist    {}
email    {display:block;}
from    {font-style:bold;}
to    {font-family:Verdana;}
sub    {}
```

Now, can I have two different properties for the same element? For example, for the 1st  element, I want to have font family Verdana while in the 2nd, I want Arial. How do I do that with the css file? Please write the code changes required for the xml and css files.

I think you may consider [CSS Two different styles for the same field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686212/css-two-different-styles-for-the-same-field) a duplicate, but the question was not answered well enough. So I posted the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inline Styles

The most obvious way would be to add inline styles to the elements. Here's one of them:

```
<email style="font-family: 'Arial';"> ... </email>
```

---

### IDs and Classes

A cleaner way would be to add a unique [ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) for every element you want to target individually, or add [classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html%5C) if you are going to repeat styles.

I don't think I need to provide an example here.

---

### CSS Selectors

But the method that would require the least change to your XML would probably be going with CSS selectors, specifically the [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) one.

So your CSS would look like:

```
email:nth-child(2) {
    font-family: 'Verdana';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could assign different [classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html) or unique [ids](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors) to the elements, use the [`:nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) selector (CSS3 only), or use inline styles.